# How to generate a unique invoice id in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I need to make Sails generate an unique ID for my invoices with the current format:

```
 <auto-incremented-number>/<current-year>
```

like: `8/2016`, `122/2099`, `122/2100`

the idea was to follow the example in the documentation

```
 function getLatestId() {
   //stuck here
   return 42;
 }

 const current_year = new Date().getFullYear()
 const calculated_id = getLatestId() +"/"+ current_year

 Invoice.create({ data:'...', id: calculated_id }).exec(function (err, item){
   if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }

   sails.log('Invoice created:', item.id);
   return res.ok();
 });
```

The problem is that even with a working `getLatestId` function the code is ugly and it code smells from a mile.

Even trying to update the id in the exec callback of the create function looks odd, because an item with a specific id is already created.

I cannot believe that sails doesn't have something to address a similar scenario, but I can't find anything in the docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to check if this generated ID exist

2.To generate uID under node use crypto

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const uID = crypto.randomBytes(2).toString('hex');
```

Example:

```
'use strict';
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateID(callback) {
  let uID = crypto.randomBytes(2).toString('hex'); //eg.uID = 3d4f
  let current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
  let uID = uID +"/"+ current_year;

  Invoice.findOne({id: uID}).exec(function(err, invoice) {
    if(err) {
      //catch Error
    } else {
      if(invoice) {
        // nope... uID exist
        return generateID(callback);
      } else {
        return callback(uID)
      }
    }
  });
}

generateID(function (uID) {
  Invoice.create({ data:'...', id: uID }).exec(function (err, item) {
    if (err) {
      // return res.serverError(err);  <-- It's bad idea sending whole err to client. It's may expose your app architecture
      sails.log.error(err);
      return res.serverError({errCode: 001, message: '<Your custom message>'});
    } else {
      sails.log('Invoice created:', item.id);
      // return res.ok(); <-- It's OK, but if u use new version of sailsJS you should have created response (201). You can see code in responses/created.js
      return res.created();
    }

  });
});
```

Here is few another methods to generate random: https://blog.tompawlak.org/generate-random-values-nodejs-javascript

Comment: Technically the IDs have to be sequential, but I get your approach